# CC.NET Checkout Based on TFS Label

Tags: tfs, cruisecontrol.net

How do you pull code based on a build label from Team Foundation Server in CruiseControl.NET.

```
<sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="true">
  <server>http://tfs.internal.com:8080/</server>
  <username>*********</username>
  <password>*********</password>
  <domain>corp</domain>
  <project>$/Code</project>
  <workingDirectory>D:\BuildServer\Lane1\SourceCode\</workingDirectory>
  <cleanCopy>false</cleanCopy>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Visual%20Studio%20Team%20Foundation%20Server%20Plugin.html) for CruiseControl.NET TFS plugin (from codeplex):

```
<sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="true">
  <server>http://my_team_foundation_server:8080</server>
  <username>my_user</username>
  <password>my_password</password>
  <domain>my_domain</domain>
  <project>$/Foobar</project>
  <workingDirectory>c:\projects\Foobar</workingDirectory>
  <cleanCopy>false</cleanCopy>
  <workspace>my_workspace_name</workspace>
  <deleteWorkspace>false</deleteWorkspace>
</sourcecontrol>
```

I do not see this as an option.

I did look at the general TFS sourcecontrol [block documentation here](http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/VSTS%20Team%20Foundation%20Server%20Source%20Control%20Block.html) and you may be able to use  as a way to passing the label as a parameter to the executable. I have not ever tried that with Visual Studio but maybe you can figure out what if you can use dynamicValues as a parameter for specifying your label against the compiler. If not, I do not think CruiseControl.NET can support these TFS features.